# Server rails s doesn't start when I add carrierwave.rb into config/initializers/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to get my image upload work with S3 but when I create
config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

and add

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|                                                                                                                                                                                 
  config.fog_credentials = {                                                                                                                                                                                      
    # Configuration for Amazon S3 should be made available through an Environment variable.                                                                                                                       
    # For local installations, export the env variable through the shell OR                                                                                                                                       
    # if using Passenger, set an Apache environment variable.                                                                                                                                                     
    #                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    # In Heroku, follow http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars                                                                                                                                          
    #                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    # $ heroku config:add S3_KEY=your_s3_access_key S3_SECRET=your_s3_secret S3_REGION=eu-west-1 S3_ASSET_URL=http://assets.example.com/ S3_BUCKET_NAME=s3_bucket/folder                                          

    # Configuration for Amazon S3                                                                                                                                                                                 
    :provider              => 'AWS',                                                                                                                                                                              
    :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_KEY'],                                                                                                                                                                      
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'],                                                                                                                                                                   
    #region                => ENV['S3_REGION']                                                                                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                               

  # For testing, upload files to local `tmp` folder.                                                                                                                                                              
  #if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?                                                                                                                                                                      
  #  config.storage = :file                                                                                                                                                                                       
  #  config.enable_processing = false                                                                                                                                                                             
  #  config.root = "#{Rails.root}/tmp"                                                                                                                                                                            
  #else                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  #  config.storage = :fog                                                                                                                                                                                        
  #end                                                                                                                                                                                                            

  # To let CarrierWave work on heroku                                                                                                                                                                             
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"                                                                                                                                                                  
  config.fog_directory    = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']                                                                                                                                                                 

  # Generate http:// urls. Defaults to :authenticated_read (https://)                                                                                                                                             
  #config.s3_access_policy = :public_read                                                                                                                                                                         
  #config.fog_host         = "#{ENV['S3_ASSET_URL']}/#{ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']}"                                                                                                                                    
end
```

rails s doesn't even start

I get bunch of errors like so..

```
=> Booting WEBrick                                                                                                                                                                                                
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000                                                                                                                                       
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options                                                                                                                                                                 
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server                                                                                                                                                                                      
Exiting
```

> from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in
>   `each'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in`
>   block in '
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `instance_exec'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   run'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
>   `block in run_initializers'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in`block in
>   tsort_each'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2
>   levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in`block (2
>   levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in
>   `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in`block in
>   each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in
>   `each'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in`
>   tsort_each_child'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in
>   each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in`each'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in
>   `tsort_each'
>           from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in`
>   tsort_each'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
>   `run_initializers'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in`
>   initialize!'
>           from /Users/atoder/Sites/rails_projects/post_app/config/environment.rb:5:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from /Users/atoder/Sites/rails_projects/post_app/config.ru:3:in`require'
>           from /Users/atoder/Sites/rails_projects/post_app/config.ru:3:in `block in
>   <main>'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`
>   instance_eval'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in
>   `initialize'
>           from /Users/atoder/Sites/rails_projects/post_app/config.ru:in`new'
>           from /Users/atoder/Sites/rails_projects/post_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`
>   eval'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in
>   `new_from_string'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`
>   parse_file'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in
>   `build_app_and_options_from_config'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in`
>   app'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in
>   `app'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in`
>   wrapped_app'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in
>   `log_to_stdout'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in`
>   start'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in
>   `block in server'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`
>   tap'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in
>   `server'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`
>   run_command!'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from /Users/atoder/Sites/rails_projects/post_app/bin/rails:8:in`require'
>           from /Users/atoder/Sites/rails_projects/post_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in`
>   load'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in
>   `call'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in`
>   call'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in
>   `run'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/bin/spring:48:in`
>   '
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in
>   `load'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`
>   '
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`
>   require'
>           from /Users/atoder/Sites/rails_projects/post_app/bin/spring:16:in `'

Comment: Are `S3_KEY`, `S3_SECRET`, and `S3_BUCKET_NAME` set?

Comment: @KenStipek yep.. I have them set for heroku and also in my application.yml file

Comment: So you if you open up the rails console and run `puts env['S3_KEY']` it spits out the key?

Comment: Not it's giving me an error when I do that as well

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out the problem... the settings from application.yml were not getting loaded.. I fixed it by adding this to application.rb

```
if File.exists?(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__))
  ENV.update YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../application.yml', __FILE__))) 
end
```